# PrimeFaces menubar, last menuitem on float:right

Tags: css, primefaces

i have this menubar in my project, i'm using **PrimeFaces** for the first time:

```
<p:menubar styleClass="sso_header ui-widget-header " style="width:99.5%; margin-top: 3px; border-radius: 10px;" >
    <p:menuitem value="Test" rendered="true" 
                style="border: 1px solid; margin-right: 5px;" icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-s" />
    <p:menuitem value="LOG IN" rendered="true" 
                style="border: 1px solid; margin-right: 5px;" icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-s" />
</p:menubar>
```

I need last menuitem `float:right;`, at least I tried to include external style in this way:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/style.css" />
```

and assign my css class to the menutitem.

I tried inline style whit the `!important` attribute, nothing works.

After inspect code from browser i noticed that Primefaces assign my style to a `<a>` inside a `<li>`.

**There is a way to assign float right to that `<li>` in PrimeFaces?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the html code that PrimeFaces is generating and use the css classes to define your styles, for your posted code something like this should work

```
.sso_header .ui-menuitem.ui-widget.ui-corner-all:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```